# Trazer determinado registro primeiro em consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá! Tudo bem?

Tenho um sistema de cadastro de imagens em uma página de portfólio.

Em meu banco de dados possuo uma tabela com uma coluna para o caminho da imagem e uma coluna chamada principal que é um char(1) que pode ser 'S' ou 'N'.

Nesse sistema preciso que o registro que tiver 'S' no campo principal seja a primeira linha no resultado da consulta.

Pois a imagem principal precisa ser o primeiro registro no resultado da consulta SQL para poder montar a galeria.

Existe no MySQL uma maneira de fazer isso.

Comment: Existe sim, posta sua consulta para poder ajudar com isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça o ajuste no `ORDER BY` da `query`:

```
...
ORDER BY CASE principal WHEN 'S' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

A cláusula `ORDER BY` indica como a apresentação dos dados será ordenada. No caso acima dizemos que, caso a coluna `principal` contenha o valor `S` então a primeira verificação de ordem receberá 0.

Comment: Muito obrigado!